# UIAlertController doesnt popup

Tags: ios, objective-c

At the end of a process of doing backup I want to let the user know the backup is complete. I used to use UIAlertView, which works. However its depreciated so was swapping out these for UIAlertController. After the popup message is complete the window closes. The new UIAlertController doesnt seem to work in this situation. What am I doing wrong?

**This is happening and the END of the process right before the view closes. The last line in the code below is closing the view. UIAlertView must be modal or something that stops the view from closing?**

I used to use this code and it worked great.

```
    UIAlertView *myalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:Msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [myalert show];

   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And this new code you dont see anything

```
  UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                  message:Msg
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* okButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {

                                   [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                               }];


    [alert addAction:okButton];



    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];



   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: why you added this line ?    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

Comment: Mark answer issue resolved

Comment: This is happening and the END of the process right before the view closes. The last line in the code below is closing the view. UIAlertView must be modal or something that stops the view from closing?

Answer (score 1):

This line looks wrong:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Try removing that or putting it somewhere more suitable. I'd suggest that you are immediately presenting and then dismissing the alert.

Comment: This is happening and the END of the process right before the view closes. The last line in the code below is closing the view. UIAlertView must be modal or something that stops the view from closing?

Answer (score 1):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Remove this line as you are presenting alert and quickly dismissing the View in which the alert was presented.

In short you are showing alert and removing the view on which the alert was shown

Comment: This is happening and the END of the process right before the view closes. The last line in the code below is closing the view. UIAlertView must be modal or something that stops the view from closing?